# How to get back the text formats like filtered_html, full_html or php_code for wysiwyg

Tags: 7, wysiwyg, input-formats

I accidentally removed the text formats like:

- Full HTML
- Filtered HTML
- PHP Code

from admin > config > content authoring > text formats.

I want to get them back but couldn't find a way. I re-installed the third party editor (ckeditor) for wysiwyg and also reinstalled the wysiwyg module, but it didn't help.

Comment: This is bug [Disabled text formats can't be seen in the GUI](https://www.drupal.org/node/2502637).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You soudln't disable text formats on config > content authoring. Now you only can edit your site's database tables. Table "filter_format" has column "status" and rows with text formats names. Change values in "status" column to 1 for each format you want be enabled.

Comment: I changed their values form 0 to 1 in my database, but I cant find them in admin>config>content authoring>text format. What might be the problem?

Comment: Hey, I got it working. All I had to do after that step was to clear cache by going to admin>config>development>performance>clear cache. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: Glad to help you

Comment: Thanks for this.  Seems like if removing one of the 3 default formats has the potential to cause so much trouble that it should not be allowed to remove them.

Comment: @squarecandy Nah, what if someone only wants plain text? It doesn't make sense to have content types that you'll never use. That could have security implications.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 8:

1. Export the configuration of the disabled filter
   (under <kbd>/admin/config/development/configuration/single/export</kbd>)
2. Change the line `status: false` to `status: true`
3. Import the configuration
   (under <kbd>/admin/config/development/configuration/single/import</kbd>)

After this, the previously disabled text filter will be listed under <kbd>/admin/config/content/formats</kbd> again.